# Specify The Version of django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been having a problem that I know about, but cannot seem to find the solution for. I need to run `python 3.2.2` and `django 1.6.5` and when I use the django-admin command it works, but causes problems because `django-admin --version 1.7b3` and not `1.6.x`

I am running ubuntu and was wondering if someone knew how to downgrade django-admin to version `1.6.x`

I have re-installed everything and not sure what is going wrong in that everything else is installed right

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking about the version of django-admin, which is simply a script that comes with Django, but about the version of Django itself.

You don't say how you installed Django in the first place. The best way is to use `pip`: to install a specific version, you would do:

```
pip install django==1.6.5
```

Comment: I do install django that way, but I always get the error `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.` I look run django-admin --version' and keep getting back '1.7b3' and when I go into the settings file I see `django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` is autogenerated and that is a `django 1.7` and when I go into terminal to check it shows that when I import django that it is version 1.6.5

Comment: That's an Apache error, so is this on your production server? In which case we'll need to know more about the way things are installed. Is Django served from inside a virtualenv - if so, do you have that activated when you installed? If not, are you logging in as the same user that Apache is running as?

Comment: It is installed on virtualenv and it is running on my local machine, how do you activate virtualenv? Though pointing back to the issue of python admin installing django version 1.7 stuff instead of version 1.6